# Postgresql: create index issue"Index row requires 23653 maximum size 8191" error 54000

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to create an index with include columns.
One of the include column "memo" is type byteA and has huge amount of data.

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_memo ON dbo.tbl_memo
(crtdate ASC,Inov ASC)
INCLUDE(memo,type)
```

This is not working with error max size 8191.

I tried to create extension btree_gist and postgis based on docs.
Still I am getting same error

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: you cannot do that. I guess you are trying to get an index-only scan that way. Try to avoid fetching these big attributes all the time.

Comment: Thanks. The column which I am trying to include  is of byteA type. So how do I create index on that column.

Comment: You cannot do that.